# How do you make an adjustment layer use a hex value?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

To help learn, I decided to paint my wall in Photoshop.  I created a selection with the pen tool, new layer mask, new adjustment layer.  I can use Hue/Saturation and change the colors.  But what I can't do is match a paint color exactly.  For example, if I have this hex value, #6C6A66, how do I get the wall that color?  If I do a color fill layer, it looks horrible, because well, it's a fill layer, not an adjustment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a **Photo Filter Adjustment Layer** where you can put an Hex Color Number (at the middle of the image).

But is a Photo Filter, that depends on the result to get. I think a **Color Fill Adjustment Layer** with Color Blend is a good solution (At the left).

[image: Photo Filter]

A good trick could be duplicating the **Photo Filter Adjustment Layer** (the central block of the image), the result is much refined than the Color Fill Layer:

[image: refine]

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage you to use Curves Adjustment. The issue being control. If you have a wall it isn't one color, it's got tones created by texture, paint inconsistencies, and light/shadows. A Curves Adjustment is a better approach for this because you're going to have to specify what point you want to be exactly #6C6A66 --- probably a midpoint.

I used [Odette by Jean-Philippe Delberghe on Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/exBd9GXAFhs) for this example. I didn't spend much time on the mask so its a little rough but you get the idea. Where the Info Point is placed is exactly #6C6A66 with the curves adjustment turned on.

[image]